# How to convert varchar to time without changing values in Snowflake?

Tags: time, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert a time value stored as varchar into "time" data value. But when I do the conversion it added 19 hours to my original value. I need as result the same value but converted to time.

```
SELECT '00:51:09' AS ORIGINAL_TIME_VARCHAR,
TO_TIME('00:51:09') AS CONVERT_TO_TIME;
```

the result in the time conversion looks: 19:51:09

Comment: Works fine for me - running your SQL gives '00:51:09' for both columns. Is the SQL given the exact statement you are running?

Comment: what is your local time zone ? Check if your time zone and PST time difference is 19hrs ?

Comment: my timezone is PST, how to convert the time to CST

Comment: You can try this CONVERT_TIMEZONE function in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the time zone. Converting time zones is not a straight forward process with time data.

You can use this if you want a quick solution:

```
SELECT '00:51:09' AS ORIGINAL_TIME_VARCHAR,
TO_TIME('00:51:09') - INTERVAL '19 HOURS' AS CONVERT_TO_TIME;
```